# How can get a Range of Cell of Table in a Shape (VBA Word)?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-table

I have a table put in a Shape of Word.

I want get a Range in Cell(2,1) at Text ="123"

[image]

I try this code , but it can't get a Range of Cell of Table in Shape:

```
Dim oApp As Object
Dim oShape As Object
Dim oTable As Object
Dim oDoc As Object

Set oApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oApp.Visible = True

Set oDocument = oApp.Documents.Open("E:\2022\t1.docx")
Set oShape = oDocument.Shapes(1)
Set oTable = oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Tables(1)

Dim iStart As Integer
Dim iEnd As Integer
iStart = oTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Start
iEnd = iStart + 3
oDocument.Range(iStart, iEnd).Text = "ABC"
```

Notes:

My code will working, if table put in document. But not working when table put in a Shape

How can get a Range of Cell of Table in a Shape?

Comment: Have you tried just `oTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = "ABC"`?

Comment: Your code will replace a paragraph, not a range in paragraph.

Comment: You need to be clearer in what you want then, you want to get the range of say, the first 3 characters of the cell's first paragraph? Set a `Range` variable to `oTable.Cell(2,1).Range.Paragraphs(1).Range` first then use `SetRange` to adjust the range. @DT

Comment: Yes, I want get a Range of Cell at any position of Cell. Ex: from character 1-3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the range of the cell to a variable first then use `SetRange` method to adjust the range before doing what you want:

Below will change the text of the first 3 characters in the `Cell(2,1)` 1st paragraph to "ABC":

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = oTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Paragraphs(1).Range

rng.SetRange rng.Start, rng.Start + 3
rng.Text = "ABC"
```